# $G_\delta$ spaces are $R_0$

Tags: general-topology

First some definitions:

> A space is called a [$G_\delta$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_space) (sometimes also called *perfect space*) if every closed set is a $G_\delta$.  Equivalently, if every open set is an $F_\sigma$.
>
> Two points $a$ and $b$ are [topologically distinguishable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_indistinguishability) if there is some open set containing $a$ and not $b$, or containing $b$ and not $a$.  For example, in a $T_0$ space any two points are topologically distinguishable.
>
> A space is called an [$R_0$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) if for any two topologically distinguishable points each has a nbhd not including the other point.  Equivalently, if the Kolmogorov quotient of the space is $T_1$. (The wikipedia article lists many other equivalent characterizations.)

The following result should be true:

> **Proposition:** Every $G_\delta$ space is $R_0$.

Can anyone provide a proof?

Perfectly normal spaces are completely regular, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525139).  Since perfectly normal spaces are exactly the normal $G_\delta$ spaces, the result above provides another way of proving this, in combination with the fact that $R_0$ normal spaces are completely regular as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990826).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a $G_\delta$ topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and let $x, y \in X$ be distinguishable points. W.L.O.G. we take O to be an open neighborhood of $x$ not containing $y$. Since $X\setminus O$ is a closed set and $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a $G_\delta$ space, there is a countable collection of open sets $V_i$ such that $\bigcap_{i\in \mathbb{N}} V_i = X\setminus O$. Now given that $y\in X\setminus O$ and $x\notin X\setminus O$, there is an $i_0 \in \mathbb{N}; y\in V_{i_0}$ and $x\notin V_{i_0}$ making $(X,\mathcal{T})$ an $R_0$ space.

Something similar has been stated in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166864121003667) by Mykhaylyuk et. al. They proved that any $G_\delta$ partial metric space, which is essentially $T_0$, is $T_1$.

Comment: I guess we could also argue more directly using $O$ is an $F_\sigma$ and take some closed set contained in $O$ and containing $x$, etc?  Would that even work in the more general case that any open set is a union of closed set (or the dual) even if not countable union?  Not sure what kind of more general spaces would satisfy that.

Comment: The property will still hold if any closed set is an intersection of open sets, or equivalently any open set is a union of closed set. It would be an interesting topic to investigate.

Comment: Actually, $R_0$ are exactly the spaces for which open sets are union of closed sets (equivalently, every open set contains the closure of any of its points).  See items 8 and 9 in the list of characterizations for $R_0$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space.  And $G_\delta$ spaces are the ones where open sets are countable unions of closed sets.  So one implies the other.